# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY on Xiaomi K20 Pro

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio 4.1. I created a basic authentication app using phone number. I tried to run it on my Android Device using USB Debugging. App isn't getting installed.

```
01/03 15:05:57: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi K20 Pro.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

List of apks:
[0] 'D:\WorkSpace\SmartSquad\pBunk\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'null'
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

The following is AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.first.pBunk">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PBunk">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />

        <!--
               Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
               app to run.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SignedIn"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_signed_in">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please add your AndroidManifest.xml to the question. It's usually related to a dependency declared there.

Comment: I added the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: The problem is most likely `com.google.android.wearable`. This library is only available on Android wearable devices, not on smartphones. Try to remove both the `uses-library` and the `meta-data` entry.